# global name 'request' is not defined error comes instead of it going to a template

Tags: django

Hi my code below produces the error global name 'request' is not defined. I am using django. What am i doing wrong? I want it to go to the template np_orders.html if the person has never made an order.

```
class OrderList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
queryset = Order.objects.all()

def get_queryset(self):
    try:
        user_check_email = self.request.user.email
        user_checkout = UserCheckout.objects.get(email=user_check_email)
        return super(OrderList, self).get_queryset().filter(user=user_checkout)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'no_orders.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have not added the `request` as a parameter to the view function.

```
class OrderList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
queryset = Order.objects.all()

def get_queryset(self,request):
    try:
        user_check_email = self.request.user.email
        user_checkout = UserCheckout.objects.get(email=user_check_email)
        return super(OrderList, self).get_queryset().filter(user=user_checkout)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return render(request, 'no_orders.html')
```

Check this documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/